# Segmentation Fault on an Online Compiler and VScode Insiders gives me [Done] exited with code=3221225725

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, visual-studio-code, segmentation-fault

Program to Create a Matrix with user imput and search an element in it.
Getting a Segmentation Fault when compiled it on an Online Compiler and VScode Insiders gives me [Done] exited with code=3221225725 in 1.181 seconds.

[Online Compiler used.](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/)

VScode+MingW also used.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int p;
    do 
    {
        int i,j,k,m;
        int a[j];
                
        m=0;
        
        cout<<"Enter The Number Of Elements You Want In Your Array.\n";
        cin>>j;
        
        cout<<"Give Your Input For The Array.\n";
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i];
        }
    
        cout<<endl<<"Your Array Is:\n";
        
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            cout<<a[i]<<endl;
        }
        
        cout<<"Enter The Number You Want To Check.\n";
        cin>>k;
        
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==k)
            {
                m=1;
            }
        }
        if(m==1)
        {
            cout<<"You Number "<<k<<" Is Listed.\n";
        }

        else
        {
            cout<<"You Number "<<k<<" Is Not Listed.\n";
        }

        cout<<"If You Want A Re-Run Press 1 Or Else Press Any Other Number.\n";
        cin>>p;
    } 
    while(p==1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [your compiler's warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/Erad1hxhv)?

Comment: `3221225725` is the same as `0xc00000fd` which means stack overflow https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/enp7oy/what_does_3221225725_0xc00000fd_exit_code_means/

Comment: @drew Yup..No errors there.

Comment: You should adjust your compilers arguments to warn about this. You should get the same warnings as @DrewDormann if compiled with warnings enabled. And pay attention to warnings as they indicate possible broken code.

Comment: @drescherjm  I didn't get that as such..But Thank u anyway

Comment: You do so by editing your `tasks.json` file in the .vscode folder. The important flags were `-Wall -Wextra`  you can add that to the args: line inside the quotes.

Comment: This blog explains that: [https://zhihaoruan.xyz/2019/04/29/vscode-cpp/](https://zhihaoruan.xyz/2019/04/29/vscode-cpp/)

Answer (score 0):

`int a[j];` is executed with uninitialized `j`. Also note that *Variable-Length Arrays* (VLA) is not in the standard C++. You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector> // add this to use std::vector

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int p;
    do 
    {
        int i,j,k,m;
        // delete this
        //int a[j];
                
        m=0;
        
        cout<<"Enter The Number Of Elements You Want In Your Array.\n";
        cin>>j;
        
        // allocate an array *after* reading j
        std::vector<int> a(j);

        cout<<"Give Your Input For The Array.\n";
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i];
        }
    
        cout<<endl<<"Your Array Is:\n";
        
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            cout<<a[i]<<endl;
        }
        
        cout<<"Enter The Number You Want To Check.\n";
        cin>>k;
        
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==k)
            {
                m=1;
            }
        }
        if(m==1)
        {
            cout<<"You Number "<<k<<" Is Listed.\n";
        }

        else
        {
            cout<<"You Number "<<k<<" Is Not Listed.\n";
        }

        cout<<"If You Want A Re-Run Press 1 Or Else Press Any Other Number.\n";
        cin>>p;
    } 
    while(p==1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hello @MikeCat...Thank You for ur response...but I haven't learnt `#include<vector>` as of now..I have started cpp about 2 weeks ago...and have not come across `#include<vector>`...so is there any alternative to it?

Comment: If you want to keep with the non standard VLA you need to move `int a[j];` to after you retrieve the value of `j` not before. `c++` executes your code line by line starting at the top (ignoring the optimizer)

Comment: @drescherjm So Should I declare my Array after taking my input from the user?

Comment: Yes because before that `j` has not been initialized. And you are telling your compiler to create an array with the size of `j` using this uninitialized / garbage value as a size. The size of the array is not dynamic. It will not change later on when `j` changes.